# Running Npm on Git bash gives Bad address error

Tags: node.js, npm, git-bash

Whenever I try to run any npm commands from git bash, I am getting this error:

```
/c/nodejs/npm: line 34: /c/nodejs/node.exe: Bad address
```

Even `npm -v` gives the above error. Npm works fine from windows cmd though. I want npm to work from both git bash and windows cmd.